# Kotlin type mismatch error when passing the arguments from the terminal

Tags: kotlin

When I tried to learn the syntax of kotlin, I found a type mismatch error.
The file test1.kt is as follow:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>){
  println(maxOf(args[0], args[1]))
  println(maxOf2(args[0], args[1]))
}

fun maxOf(a: Int, b: Int): Int{
  return if (a>b) a else b
}

fun maxOf2(a: Int, b: Int): Int = if (a>b) a else b
```

I compiled the program by typing the command on terminal.

```
kotlinc test1.kt -include-runtime -d test1.jar
```

And the error message shows:

```
test1.kt:3:18: error: type mismatch: inferred type is String but Int was expected
  println(maxOf2(args[0], args[1]))
                 ^
test1.kt:3:27: error: type mismatch: inferred type is String but Int was expected
  println(maxOf2(args[0], args[1]))
                          ^
```

The problem can be fixed by replacing

```
println(maxOf2(args[0], args[1]))
```

with

```
println(maxOf2(args[0].toInt(), args[1].toInt()))
```

My problem is why the error only happens in the function "maxOf2"?

Comment: The arguments you provide to your function are of type `String`. You can convert them to `Int` with the `toInt` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because there is another [maxOf](http://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.comparisons/max-of.html) to get the max of `Comparable`, and `String` **is-A** `Comparable`.

```
fun <T : Comparable<T>> maxOf(a: T, b: T): T
```

Comment: So the maxOf called in the second line is not the function I implemented?
Thanks :)

Comment: @T.H.Chen yes. You didn't **define** any `maxOf2` funtion for the `Comparable` rather than didn't  **implemented**. When say didn't **implement** means you have **defined** but do nothing for it. they are different meanings.:)